# Sudden syntax error after deployment

Tags: symfony, deployment, twig, composer-php

I have a working symfony project. I have it on a private bitbucked repository and locally the website works without an issue.

Today I tried to deploy the project onto an external server **linuxpl.com**.

Steps taken include:

- Istalling composer
- Adding the mysql database
- Running `git clone` to get the data into a proper location
- Running `composer install` on the folder to install everything and connect to the db
- Cleared the cache
- Set the project root as `....domain/project_name/web`

However after completing all these steps, when running the website with regular `server:run` I'm getting this odd error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in /home/spirifer/domains/surowcewobiektywie.pl/konkurs/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 1571

Not sure if this is of any importance but the mentioned code partion looks like this in my local files:

```
 // Some objects throw exceptions when they have __call, and the method we try
    // to call is not supported. If ignoreStrictCheck is true, we should return null.
    try {
        $ret = $object->$method(...$arguments);
    } catch (BadMethodCallException $e) {
        if ($call && ($ignoreStrictCheck || !$env->isStrictVariables())) {
            return;
        }
        throw $e;
    }
```

The local version **does not differ** from the one on the server.

My local machine has **PHP 7.0.9** and the remove server has **PHP 7.0.14**

How could I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PHP 5.6 adds Variadic functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list), with "...". However, Twig v1.x only required the use of PHP 5.2.7 or above.

If you didn't explicitly update to Twig 2.0, it's very possible you have used the '[death star](https://thephp.cc/news/2017/02/death-star-version-constraint)' version constraint in the composer file - '*'. which allows uncontrolled version updates to the latest version. If this is the case, you will need to either update your version of PHP, or at least require just a previous version of Twig/twig, "^1.32" would be the latest in the version 1 series of Twig.

Comment: My twig is `"twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0",` in composer.json
I added an edit to the question about php versions, please see it

Comment: Setting it like said and running composer update fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, the fact that you received that error indicates that there is more than one PHP version installed on your system and the Symfony command was executed not using the PHP 7.x binary.